# How to assert JQuery expression in Capybara?

Tags: jquery, capybara

I should check that element with tag article and with the particular class is the first in array in the DOM. I wrote JQuery expression witch is working:

```
$($('article')[0]).hasClass('styles__highlighted___2C5Yh')'
```

And checked in the console that only `0` element returns `true`. After that I created such step definition:

```
Then(/^Tag "(.*)" has the first element "(.*)"/) do |text, identifier|
  page.execute_script("$($('#{text}')[0]).hasClass('#{identifier}')")
end
```

In my test:

```
Then Tag "article" has the first element "styles__highlighted___2C5Yh"
```

It passed with `0` and with another number (when I run test), but the jQuery expression in the console returns true only with `0`. I think that I should modify my step definition file in some way but don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two technical issues with this.

1. You want to deal with the result of the JS, but you're using `execute_script` instead of `evaluate_script`
2. You're not actually expecting on anything

If we fix both of those we would get

```
Then(/^Tag "(.*)" has the first element "(.*)"/) do |text, identifier|
  result = page.evaluate_script("$($('#{text}')[0]).hasClass('#{identifier}')")
  expect(result).to be true # RSpec - will be different if using minitest
end
```

That would fix your code, however it's really not a great way of testing what you want since it can lead to flaky tests on dynamic pages (no waiting retrying)

The best solution would depend on the exact structure of the page.  For instance if all of the 'article' elements are sibling elements then you could do something like

```
Then(/^The first article should be highlighted$/) do
  expect(page).to have_selector('article.styles__highlighted___2C5Yh:first-of-type')
end
```

A less optimal option (still better than the jQuery though) would be something along the lines of

```
first_article = find('article', match: :first)
expect(first_article).to match_css('.styles__highlighted___2C5Yh')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
Fixed it changing in that way:

```
Then(/^Tag "(.*)" has the first element "(.*)"/) do |text, identifier|
  result = page.evaluate_script("$($('#{text}')[0]).hasClass('#{identifier}')")
  result.should be true
end
```